# CodeIgniter - Where to place scripts with

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm not sure if this is the right place, but since you seem to be able to answer almost anything, I'll give it a try...

I am trying to convert my website, to use the *CodeIgniter* framework, and it is going okay I believe. I followed the tutorial and made a controller, which can show all the basic pages. However, I would like to place PHP scripts (like the one for logging in) in a separate folder, so that i have the following:

- /application/
- - /views/
- - - /pages/
- - - /scripts/
- - - / templates/

The *pages* subfolder is the one containing the normal sites, whereas the *scripts* folder contains the scripts (sorry for the weird layout, using lists). I tried to modify the controller from pages, to work on scripts, so it looks like this:

```
<?php

class Scripts extends CI_Controller {

    public function run($page = 'home') {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/scripts/'.$page.'.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        // Connect to database, using configuration from /application/config/database.php
        $this->load->database();

         // Capitalize the first letter
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        // Wrap header and footer around content, to define layout
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('scripts/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}

?>
```

And then I try to call a script in a file, located in /application/views/scripts/, called createNewProject.php, with the following URL: `"/index.php/Scripts/run/createNewProject"`. However, all I get in return is a 404-error. What am I doing wrong, and am I even using good practice, in regards to script placements?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps APPPATH gives an url with a trailing "/", try

```
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/scripts/'.$page.'.php')) {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }
```

instead!